# Android native Floodfill implementation out of Memory

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native-code

we are working on an image editing app. For the Floodfill Algorithm we use native Code (jnibitmap.cpp).
Sometimes when we perform the algorithm, we get OOM Error "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)".
As we can see in the memory monitor, we haven't reached the heap-border, but the available unallocated memory is very small ( < 1 MB). When it's over 2 MB, it's always working.
We thought that the problem is the native code, so the android memory management can't react on the increased memory usage.

Comment: I don't understand what is your question.

Comment: "Fatal signal 11" is not an out-of-memory error, it's a "you just accessed memory you shouldn't have" error.  Check the native crash dump in logcat to see where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem Willi is trying to desribe is the following:

They are developing an Android painting app like Paint for Microsoft. For the fill tool, they use an algortihm called floodfill, but in native code implemented.

The problem seems to be some memory issue, because calling the native implementation through the java code crashes the app. They have monitored the heap and found, that it crashes if the free heap memory is smaller 1 MB.

So what he is trying to ask is how to prevent the native code of running out of memory. What I know is that the java runtime has no information about the memory need of the native code and it sounds like floodfill only crashes if the application itself has low free memory and don't allocate more for the native code.

HTH